# On every click text should add in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add value on every click on my function.

for example i click on  then value is coming but i want to click again and another value should come without replacing the existing value

```
  <script>
    function dearq(selected){

      var value = $(".textvaluenonw").val();
          $("#dearname").html(value);

    }

</script>
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r7P3w/12/

Comment: like this way see this [Edit](http://jsfiddle.net/r7P3w/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add text inside your `#dearName` element, just use [`$.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
function dearq(selected){

    var value = $(".textvaluenonw").val();
    $("#dearname").append(value);

}
```

Comment: thnx you dude its very nice :-)

Comment: @moomnvave if the field is blank then its not giving the blank space what to do in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the text and append

```
<script>
function dearq(selected){

  var value = $(".textvaluenonw").val();
  var newValue=$("#dearname").text()+" " + value;
      $("#dearname").html(newValue);

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  <script> 
    function dearq(selected){ 
      var value = $(".textvaluenonw").val(); 
      $("#dearname").append(value); 
    } 
</script>
```